# Tkinter Prior key giving error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def keypress(self,event):
    if event.keysym in self.keys:
        # event type 2 is key down, type 3 is key up
        self.keys[event.keysym] = event.type == '2'

def looper(self):
    if self.keys['Up']:
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(-2,'units')
    if self.keys['Down']:
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(2,'units')
    if self.keys['Left']:
        self.canvas.xview_scroll(-2,'units')
    if self.keys['Right']:
        self.canvas.xview_scroll(2,'units')
    if self.keys['Prior']:
        p = p -.01
        self.draw()
    if self.keys['Next']:
        p = p +.01
        self.draw()
```

When I run the program it comes up with the error KeyError: Prior.  I want it to recognize when I press the PageUp/Down keys so I can zoom in/out.  Without the Prior/Next it runs fine and operates like it should when I press Up/Down/Left/Right cursor keys.

Comment: Is there anywhere in your code where you initialize `self.keys['Prior']` before a user presses that key?

Comment: You need to add any keys you want to use to the initialization: `self.keys = dict.fromkeys(('Left', 'Right', 'Up', 'Down', 'Prior', 'Next'))`